# How to resolve inheritance in WPF windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-7.0

I cant quite think of a good way to achieve the following:

- I have a base window class `SlimWindow` which inherits from some 3rd party window (Devexpress)
- I have a base dialog window `SlimDialogWindow` which inherits from `SlimWindow`
- I have a base window for certain class of windows `ModuleWindow` which inherits from `SlimWindow`
- I now need to have 2 sets of windows - one are that behave the same as `SlimDialogWindow`  and another that behave like both - `SlimDialogWindow` and `ModuleWindow`. Lets say currently there are 10 windows inherit from `SlimDialogWindow` - I need to split them to 6 to behave like `SlimDialogWindow` + `ModuleWindow` and 4 to behave like `SlimDialogWindow`

`SlimDialogWindow` + `ModuleWindow` vs pure `SlimDialogWindow` - pure dialog is just a window with OK/Cancel buttons and some other functionality, `ModuleWindow` - sets some properties - e.g. remove it from task bar and alt-tab plus some other stuff.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would go with either of these approaches:

1. Create 2 versions of `SlimDialogWindow`. One that inherits `SlimWindow`, and another `SlimModuleDialogWindow` which inherits `ModuleWindow`.
   That'll give you the versatility to use either one according to the scenario. Of course I don't know how much code you have in `SlimDialogWindow`. If it's just xaml, it could be solved with a template to be used in both. For procedural code, maybe you could export it to a common class.

or use this approach:

2. Make `ModuleWindow` an optional extension of `SlimWindow`. You said it affects some properties. So maybe add a flag in the `SlimWindow` constructor - `IsModule`, to set the changed properties.
   If you want a single class for both scenarios, I don't think you have many options besides combining both.
   Thinking about it. Maybe you can have `ModuleWindow` as a single class, with a flag to disable its features. It would allow you to separate the classes, but it still amounts to the same thing.

Hope this helps

Comment: yeah I did what you describe in #1 - just copy/pasted it. btw - xaml does not enter picture in the whole thing because WPF doesnt have visual inheritance. You cannot inherit a control/window with XAML. all the inheritance described in the question are just .cs files... Ill try your #2 one day.. thanks